# Solve all for all real $x$: $9^x +6^x = 4(4^x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having some trouble finding all real solutions to $9^x +6^x = 4(4^x)$. The original equation given was $3^x(3^x + 2^x) = 4^{x+1}$. I've fiddled around with it and tried to make everything the same base, but I'm not really sure what to do. Could someone tell me where to go next? (I'm pretty sure $0$ is the only real solution, so any hints on how to prove this would be greatly appreciated, or any corrections if I'm incorrect in this belief)

Note: For those people who are suspicious of everything - I've been on math stack exchange for quite a while (as well as accounts in other communities) , but I only just created an account for this :). This question comes from some extension work my maths teacher gave me (I'm scared to ask her for help haha).

Thank you!

Comment: If the original equation was $3^x(3^x \cdot 2^x) = 4^{x + 1}$, shouldn't you have $9^x \cdot 6^x = 4 \cdot 4^x$?

Comment: "Please don't suggest using something overcomplicated such as log" The answer is a logarithm. You might as well say, "don't use $\sqrt{}$ to solve $x^2-17=0$".

Comment: What I am questioning is how you got an addition sign on the left-hand side.

Comment: Oh sorry! I typed that wrong oopsy. I'll go edit it now.

Comment: In response to J.G.: I wanted some hints on if there was a simple way to prove that $0$ was the only real solution (that is what I believe). Where one to include a logarithm in a solution, it would also not be real (I tried), which would defeat the purpose of 'all real $x$'. Sorry about that! I'll try to word my questions a little better from now on..

Comment: Observe that $0$ cannot be a solution since $9^0 + 6^0 = 1 + 1 = 2 \neq 4 = 4 \cdot 1 = 4 \cdot 4^0$.

Comment: "Where one to include a logarithm in a solution, it would also not be real (I tried),..." I don't know where you made a mistake (since you didn't share your work) but there is a real solutions that include logarithms

Answer (score 7):

Hint...divide by $4^x$ and substitute $u=(\frac32)^x$

Answer (score 0):

The zero of function
$$f(x)=9^x +6^x - 4(4^x)$$ is not $x=1$ since $f(1)=-1$ but it should close.

Consider instead
$$g(x)=\log[9^x +6^x]-\log[4(4^x)]$$ which is almost a straight line. Expand it as Taylor series
$$g(x)=-\log \left(\frac{16}{15}\right)+\frac{8}{5}  \log
   \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)(x-1)+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$ which gives, as an *estimate*,
$$x \sim 1+\frac{5 \log \left(\frac{16}{15}\right)}{8 \log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}=1.09948$$ while the solution given by Newton method is
$x=1.09918$.

Answer (score 0):

After a few manipulations you can see the exact solution is
$$ x =\frac{log(W)}{log (3) -log (2) }$$

where $W= \frac{\sqrt{17}-1}{2}$ and log representa the natural logarithm.

$x=1.099183900415395$